# Returning a vector of const from a vector of non-const

Tags: c++, vector, constants, shared-ptr

I have the following code that I'm writing for a Database class to read data from a file:

```
typedef std::vector<char> CharVec;
typedef std::vector<const char> ConstCharVec;
typedef std::shared_ptr<CharVec> CharVecPtr;
typedef std::shared_ptr<ConstCharVec> ConstCharVecPtr;

const ConstCharVecPtr DB::readData(unsigned int amount,unsigned int offset,unsigned int flag)
{
    CharVec data;
    //Add stuff to data from the file...
    //etc...
    return ConstCharVecPtr(new ConstCharVec(data.begin(),data.end()));
}
```

The return statement fails during compile with:

```
include\c++\bits\allocator.h|89|  required from 'class std::allocator<const char>'|
include\c++\bits\alloc_traits.h|86|  required from 'struct std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<const char> >'|
include\c++\ext\alloc_traits.h|90|  required from 'struct __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<const char> >'|
include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h|76|  required from 'struct std::_Vector_base<const char, std::allocator<const char> >'|
include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h|208|  required from 'class std::vector<const char>'|
C:\Users\Brian\work\cr\code\DB.cpp|86|  required from here|
```

I want to maintain the const-ness of the return value, because other functions expect the raw data from the Database to be constant, but I can't see to convert the non-const data to const. The char vector is used as a return so that the users of the raw data can feed it into functions that require the const char* pointer easily. Is there a way to accomplish this const conversion or am I better off using another return type for this kind of data?

Comment: Data inside the vector needs to be able to be modified. A `const vector<T>` works perfectly fine. I must admit I've never used a smart pointer to constant data, but I imagine it would work.

Comment: `std::vector<const T>` is pretty pointless anyway: even if you couldn't modify elements in-place, you could still remove them or put new ones in, thereby effectively mutating objects.

Comment: Awesomely enough, simply changing the typedef to 'typedef const std::vector<char> ConstCharVec' fixed a whole bunch of other stuff too! Props. This makes much more sense now, as the vector was intended to be const too.

Comment: Also note that it usually you would not dynamically allocate containers, but rather create them with automatic storage duration (stack or as member of other objects)